# PHP, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a dependable dropdown lists on PHP with AJAX calls. There are 9 columns on the MySQL table. I found a sample code. There were 3 dropdown lists. And I tried to increase them.

```html
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 3.2//en">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="">
<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxFunction(choice)
{
{
    alert(choice.options.length);}
var httpxml;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
  try
    {
    httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
  catch (e)
    {
    try
      {
      httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    catch (e)
      {
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
      return false;
      }
    }
  }
function stateChanged() 
    {
    if(httpxml.readyState==4)
      {
//alert(httpxml.responseText);
var myObject = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);

for(j=document.myForm.state.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
document.myForm.state.remove(j);
}

var state1=myObject.value.state1;

var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = 'Select State';
optn.value = '';
document.myForm.state.options.add(optn);
for (i=0;i<myObject.state.length;i++)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = myObject.state[i];
optn.value = myObject.state[i];
document.myForm.state.options.add(optn);

if(optn.value==state1){
var k= i+1;
document.myForm.state.options[k].selected=true;
}
} 

//////////////////////////
for(j=document.myForm.city.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
document.myForm.city.remove(j);
}
var city1=myObject.value.city1;
//alert(city1);
for (i=0;i<myObject.city.length;i++)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = myObject.city[i];
optn.value = myObject.city[i];
document.myForm.city.options.add(optn);
if(optn.value==city1){
document.myForm.city.options[i].selected=true;
}

} 
          
////////////////////
for(j=document.myForm.country.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
document.myForm.country.remove(j);
}

var name1=myObject.value.name1;

var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = 'Select Name';
optn.value = '';
document.myForm.country.options.add(optn);
for (i=0;i<myObject.name.length;i++)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = myObject.name[i];
optn.value = myObject.name[i];
document.myForm.country.options.add(optn);

if(optn.value==name1){
var k= i+1;
document.myForm.name.options[k].selected=true;
}
}         


///////////////////////////
document.getElementById("txtHint").style.background='#00f040';
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML='done';
//setTimeout("document.getElementById('txtHint').style.display='none'",3000)
    }
    }

var url="ajax-dd3ck.php";
var country=myForm.country.value;
if(choice != 's1'){
var state=myForm.state.value;
var city=myForm.city.value;
var name=myForm.name.value;
}else{
var state='';
var city='';
var name='';
}
url=url+"?country="+country;
url=url+"&state="+state;
url=url+"&city="+city;
url=url+"&name="+name;
url=url+"&id="+Math.random();
myForm.st.value=state;
//alert(url);
 document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML=url;
httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
 document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="Please Wait....";
document.getElementById("txtHint").style.background='#f1f1f1';
}
</script>


</head>

<body >
</head>

<body>
<div id="txtHint" style="width : 100px;background-color: #cccc33;">Message area</div>
<br><br>
<form name="myForm" action='ajax-dd3-details.php' method='post'">
<input type=hidden name=st value=0>
<table width=500>
<tr><td >
Select Country<br><select name="country" id="s1" onchange="ajaxFunction(this);">
<option value=''>Select One</option>
<?Php
//require "../include/z_db1.php";
require "config.php";// connection to database 
$sql="select distinct country from student5 ";
foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo "<option value=$row[country]>$row[country]</option>";
}
?>
</select>

</td><td ><select name=state  id="s2" onchange="ajaxFunction(this)";>
<option value=''>Select One</option></select></td>
<td ><select name=city  id="s3" onchange="ajaxFunction(this);">
<option value=''>Select One</option></select></td>
<td ><select name=sex id="s4" onchange="ajaxFunction(this);">
<option value=''>Select One</option></select></td>
</tr></tr>
<tr><td colspan=3><input type=submit value='Submit'></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
<br><br>
<div id="txtHint2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I edited this php file and added below code. Because I want to add name column from mysql to dropdown:

```html
////////////////////
for(j=document.myForm.name.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
document.myForm.name.remove(j);
}

var name1=myObject.value.name1;

var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = 'Select Name';
optn.value = '';
document.myForm.name.options.add(optn);
for (i=0;i<myObject.name.length;i++)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = myObject.name[i];
optn.value = myObject.name[i];
document.myForm.name.options.add(optn);

if(optn.value==name1){
var k= i+1;
document.myForm.name.options[k].selected=true;
}
}
```

I also edited the other php file:

```html
<?Php
require "config.php"; // connection details

error_reporting(0);// With this no error reporting will be there
//////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$country=$_GET['country'];// 
//$country='IND'; // To check you can use this
$state1=$_GET['state'];
$city1=$_GET['city'];
$name1=$_GET['name'];
//$state1="Andhra Pradesh";
///////////// Validate the inputs ////////////
// Checking country variable ///
if((strlen($country)) > 0 and (!ctype_alpha($country))){ 
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}
// Checking state variable (with space ) ///

if ((strlen($state1)) > 0 and ctype_alpha(str_replace(' ', '', $state1)) === false) {
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}
// Checking class variable ///
if((strlen($name1)) > 0 and (!ctype_alpha($name1))){ 
echo "Data Error";
exit;
}

/////////// end of input validation //////

if(strlen($country) > 0){
$q_country="select distinct(state) from student5 where country = '$country'";
}else{
$q_country="select distinct(state) from student5";
}
//echo $q_country;
$sth = $dbo->prepare($q_country);
$sth->execute();
$state = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

$q_state="select distinct(city) from student5 where ";
if(strlen($country) > 0){
$q_state= $q_state . " country = '$country' ";
}
if(strlen($state1) > 0){$q_state= $q_state . " and  state='$state1'";}
$sth = $dbo->prepare($q_state);
$sth->execute();
$city = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

$q_name="select distinct(name) from student5 where ";
if(strlen($country) > 0){
$q_state= $q_state . " country = '$country' ";
}
if(strlen($state1) > 0){$q_state= $q_state . " and  state='$state1'";}
if(strlen($city1) > 0){$q_city= $q_city . " and  city='$city1'";}
$sth = $dbo->prepare($q_city);
$sth->execute();
$name = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

$main = array('state'=>$state,'city'=>$city,'name'=>$name1, 'value'=>array("state1"=>"$state1","city1"=>"$city1", "name"=>"$name1"));
echo json_encode($main); 

////////////End of script /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
```

I added that code to above:

```html
$q_name="select distinct(name) from student5 where ";
if(strlen($country) > 0){
$q_state= $q_state . " country = '$country' ";
}
if(strlen($state1) > 0){$q_state= $q_state . " and  state='$state1'";}
if(strlen($city1) > 0){$q_city= $q_city . " and  city='$city1'";}
$sth = $dbo->prepare($q_city);
$sth->execute();
$name = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

When I open it via LAMP, new dropdown list doesn't work. And [I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOiXK.png). What can I fix this?

Edit: [And here is what i mean with "name"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2pTw.png)

Answer (score 0):

`document.myForm.name.options.length` this is giving you error. You have to use the `name` of `select` to get `options` `length`. So Use like `document.myForm.country.options.length`

So in your scenario, you have to do like this.

In HTML

```
<select name=country id='s1' onchange=ajaxFunction(this);>
```

And in JS

```
function ajaxFunction(choice) {
    alert(choice.options.length);}
```

Comment: I don't understand actually. name, country, state, city are coloumn names. I wrote "document.myForm.name.options.length" for name coloumn. What is the difference between "document.myForm.name.options.length" and "document.myForm.country.options.length". Notation is same.

Comment: `name` is a special / key word

Comment: name is a coloumn name in table. Like name, surname, city... I don't understand Subin, so I didn't.

Comment: I also added a screenshot of the table. You can see it at the end of the question.

Comment: I changed it as you said @Subin. I took another error. The message is "Uncauhgt ReferenceError: ajaxFunction is not defined". I changed "s1" as this and I got this error.

Comment: Yes over there. And I added "{alert(choice.options.length);}" as you said, on that row, I got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: I set all of them. I also updated the code. 3rd and 4th dropdowns still don't work

Comment: If I use "for(j=document.myForm.name.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)" instead of "for(j=document.myForm.country.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)", I get an error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". I can select 2nd dropdown after that I can't selecet 3rd and 4th

Comment: i'm calling it at 89th line.

Comment: for(j=document.myForm.name.options.length-1;j>=0;j--) is 89th line. and error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefinedstateChanged" @ ajax-dd3.php:89

Comment: You are totally confused with `name`. Use `country` or `state` or `city` as required instead of `name`. @Atacan

Comment: Actually I want to add more dropdowns. Name, surname, age etc. But i couldn't

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of minor errors also which will not help!

```
<form name="myForm" action='ajax-dd3-details.php' method='post' ">
<input type=hidden name=st value=0>
```

There is a spurious double quote at the end of the form opening tag, should simply be:

```
<form name="myForm" action='ajax-dd3-details.php' method='post'>
```

and you really ought to encase values with quotes in your fields...

```
<input type='hidden' name='st' value='0' />
```

Similarly for various other elements within your form, such as:-

```
<select name=country id='s1' onchange=ajaxFunction('s1');>
```

should be

```
<select name='country' id='s1' onchange="ajaxFunction('s1')">
```

I know others will likely disagree, especially as HTML5 seems more relaxed about this type of thing but it's good practice to adopt and helps figure where things are breaking.

Comment: Thanks @RamRaider. After fix this issue, I will do these.